# Python check if input variable matches format

Tags: python, if-statement, youtube

I'm attempting to make a 'check' to see if a given link matches a certain pattern. Here's what I have so far:

```
love = input("Enter URL: ")
while True:
    if love == 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*':
        print("confirm, what is love?")
        break
    else:
        print("NOT A YOUTUBE LINK")
```

`love` is supposed to be a youtube link, starting in `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` and ending in 11 wildcard characters. How would one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `startswith()` method.

```
if love.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='):
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need exactly 11 characters after the `=`, you could use regex:

```
import re

love = input("Enter URL: ")

if re.search(r"http://youtube.com/watch\?v=.{11}", love):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

The `.{11}` in the regex pattern means match any character (`.`) exactly 11 times (`{11}`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a while loop for the **if** statement like that. If you write it that way, your program will continuously print out "NOT A YOUTUBE LINK" because you have no **break** for **else**. If you put a **break** in your **else** statement, then there is no use for a **while loop**, since you stop the program after one try anyway. Also, use **startswith()** to check for the URL

If you want to use a loop, you can use it this way:

```
def checkURL(inputURL):
    if inputURL.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='):
        print("confirm, what is love?")
    else:
        print("NOT A YOUTUBE LINK")

while True:
    love = input("Enter URL: ")
    if love.lower() != "quit":
        checkURL(love)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems with your code:

1. you don't need the while loop, it will end your computer memory as long it is not a youtube link
2. You can just check if **youtube.com** in the string variable.
3. youtube domains can be **youtube.com`, **youtu.be**, and maybe some more that I don't know about. I suggest putting all of them in a list and check.